# \colorbox shape – highlight formula

Tags: color, highlighting, colorbox

I've seen somewhere such a shape of a highlight.

[image]

I am trying to repeat this using `xcolor` package, but I managed to get only rectangular shape of the box.
[image]

```
\colorbox{red!10}{$\displaystyle\int xe^{-x}dx$}
```

Comment: `\colorbox` is always rectangular, look at packages such as `tcolorbox` which has many many options for fancier boxes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can combine `tcolorbox` and `empheq`. With `\tcbhighmath` you can highlight individual subexpressions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[theorems,skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{empheq}
\tcbset{red eqbox/.style={enhanced,top=0.2ex, bottom=0.2ex, 
left=0.1ex,right=0.1ex,
overlay={\fill[red!10] (frame.south west) to[bend left] 
 (frame.north west) --  (frame.north east) to[bend left]
  (frame.south east) -- cycle;},
boxrule=0pt},
blue eqbox/.style={enhanced,top=0.2ex, bottom=0.2ex, 
left=0.1ex,right=0.1ex,
overlay={\fill[blue!10] (frame.south west) to[bend left] 
 (frame.north west) --  (frame.north east) to[bend left]
  (frame.south east) -- cycle;},
boxrule=0pt},
highlight math style=red eqbox}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[box=\tcbhighmath]{equation}
\int x \,e^{-x}\,\diff x
\end{empheq}

\begin{align}
\tcbhighmath{\int x \,e^{-x}\,\diff x}~&=
\left.\int x \,e^{-ax}\,\diff x\right|_{a=1}
\notag\\
&=
\left[-\frac{\diff}{\diff a}
\int e^{-ax}\,\diff x\right]_{a=1}
=\left[\frac{\diff}{\diff a}\frac{e^{-ax}}{a}\right]_{a=1}
\notag\\
&=~\tcbhighmath[blue eqbox]{-(1+x)e^{-x}}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can always change `highlight math style` to change the appearance.

Comment: What if I need to highlight only this integral and continue writing the equation? Could it be done without `empheq`?

Comment: @antshar Sure. I added an example.

Comment: Almost perfect. It would be nice to be able to ajust the width and height(or rather paddings) of such a highlight(using `xparse` if needed), but I can't really know how to do that. Could you help?

Comment: @antshar Sure, the top padding is stored in `top` and so on. I used these keys to make the boxes tighter. You can change the dimensions as you like.

Comment: I'd like to set those parameters individually, so I am trying to use `\tcbhighmath[.style={top=5ex}]{-(1+x)e^{-x}}` but it doesn't really seem to work.

Comment: @antshar`\tcbhighmath[.style={top=5ex}]` is not a working syntax, yes. You need to say something like `\tcbhighmath[blue eqbox,{top=2ex}]{-(1+x)e^{-x}}`. Please also consider the fact that I really tried to answer your original question, which I think I did. Comments are not meant to be a chat.

Comment: Yes, perfect now! Thank you so much. You really did answer the original question and I really appreciate the help with additional questions. I understand that it isn't a chat, by the way where can I contact you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108015/discussion-between-antshar-and-schrodingers-cat).

Comment: @antshar I am about to go to a meeting. (And it is the choice of many users like myself not to provide any contact information. That way we can decouple whenever we think it is necessary.)